# Error adding Key item to macOS keychain

Tags: swift, keychain

I have following code:

```
let keyData = UUID().uuidString.data(using: .utf8)!

var attributes: [NSString: Any] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: keyData,
]
let st1 = SecItemDelete(attributes as CFDictionary)
attributes[kSecValueData] = keyData
let st2 = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, nil)
```

I am trying to add item to the keychain with type kSecClassKey. For some reason this code works perfectly in iOS and doesn't work in macOS.
In macOS st1 is -25300 (which means The item cannot be found.) and st2 is -25299 (which means The item already exists.)
What can I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 1):

The error `errSecDuplicateItem` (-25299) might also be returned if you miss a mandatory attribute, e.g., if you try to add a `kSecClassGenericPassword` key without the `kSecAttrService` set.

In your case I wonder why you try to store the UUID as a cryptographic key (`kSecClassKey`). Storing it as a generic password (`kSecClassGenericPassword`) instead would suffice.

```swift
let keyData = UUID().uuidString.data(using: .utf8)!

var attributes: [NSString: Any] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrService: "YourApp-UUID", // Determines the purpose/context of the used password/value
    kSecAttrLabel: "YourApp (UUID)", // Name of the Keychain item
    kSecValueData: keyData, // Actual value, that will be stored securely
]
let status = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, nil)
```